# Number of samples needed to distinguish between two Bernoulli distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

In a paper I am reading, they make the following claim offhandedly (paraphrased):

> Suppose there are two Bernoulli distributions with means $p_0$ and $p_1$ where $\delta=p_1-p_0$. One distribution is chosen (by a fair coin flip) and then $n$ i.i.d. samples are drawn from it. The probability of error (incorrectly identifying the correct distribution based on the i.i.d. samples) is $\Omega(1)$ unless the number of samples is $n=\Omega(1/\delta^2)$.

What is the intuition/reasoning behind this claim? I am also confused about the setup (this claim was stated rather hastily in the paper), such as whether the two means are known or just their difference $\delta$ is known, and also what statistic (sample mean?) and procedure (pick the distribution whose mean is closer to sample mean?) is being used to infer the distribution. Any references would also be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Omega (1)$? And can you reference the paper?

Comment: Proof of the last theorem of [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3371-the-price-of-bandit-information-for-online-optimization.pdf)

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda $\Omega(1)$ means $\ge c$ for some constant $c>0$ I believe

Comment: By $CLT$, error in the average of the sample goes down as $1/\sqrt n$. Since you need resolution on the order of $\delta$, you need $\Omega(1/\delta^2)$ samples (where the constant come from how sure of your decision you want to be) . As for the set-up - you know both means and need to decide from which one the sample comes from.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks for your answer! Could you be a little more explicit? I am unsure how the statement of CLT implies your first two statements (and what your statements are saying exactly. LLN says $(\bar{X}-p) \overset{p}{\to} 0$ while CLT says $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-p) \overset{d}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,p(1-p))$, but what does "error going down as $1/\sqrt{n}$" means? And what is resolution? Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: $\delta$ is your resolution - you need to resolve between two $p_i$ whose difference is $\delta$. Error goes down as $n^{-1/2}$ means $\sigma(\bar X-p)=\Theta (n^{-1/2})$

Comment: @A.S. So the CLT implies $Var(\bar{X}-p) \sim \sigma^2/n$. If say $n \ge c/\delta^2$, then Chebychev gives $P(|\bar{X}-p|>\delta/2) \le \frac{\sigma^2/n}{\delta^2/4} \le \frac{\sigma^2}{4c}$, and we can choose $c$ large enough to make this probability smaller. However, the statement above wants a lower bound $\Omega(1)$ on the probability of error, which I guess is a lower bound on $P(|\bar{X}-p|>\delta/2)$. How do we get this lower bound?

Comment: Don't just use Chebyshev - which is weaker than CLT. Use Normal approximation directly to approximate probability of deviation.

Comment: Also note that if you don't want to over-sample, the problem is NOT to determine the mean but to differentiate between two hypothesis. For example if a sample mean is outside of $[p_1,p_2]$, you don't need that many samples to reach a certain level of confidence compared to when it's inside that region.

Comment: @A.S. Isn't the approximation good only for large $n$? Are we allowed to use the approximation for small $n$ to lower bound the tail probability?

Comment: But you are only interested in $n\to \infty$. If $n$ is bounded, it's trivial that the error is $\Omega(1)$. Normal approximation to Binomial is good if $np,n(1-p)>10$

Comment: In case others need a pointer: there are some lecture notes online that answer this question using information theory, in particular, Pinsker's inequality and Kullback-Leibler divergence.